# Does gravity have something like a maximum range of effect?

Tags: gravity

For instance, if we took a closed system free of any mass (and therefore gravitational attractors) and placed two Earth-sized bodies within it at say, 30 billion light years of each other, with no initial velocity - would they start moving towards each other over an impossibly long period of time? Or would the influence of their gravitational fields eventually "peter out" before influencing each other?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/200635/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/200781/2451  and links therein.

Answer (score 3):

It would be 30 billion years before the gravitational fields reached from one to the other. But they would attract each other with a very small force. There is no limit to the range of gravity or electromagnetism.

Answer (score 0):

$F_g = -G\cdot\frac{mM}{r^2}$, thus the limit for r going to infinity is in fact zero for gravitational force.  However since we cannot place two objects infinitely apart in the real world, there is no "range" for gravity if you will.