# Figure out at what distance object starts attracting with gravity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

For example, I have a planet and a ball. How can I figure out the distance from the planet at which the ball or other objects would start falling into the planet's gravity knowing the mass, size, and density of both objects?

I ask because I am making a physics engine.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, gravity works at any distance; see [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/200635/am-i-attracting-pluto). However, some game physics engines such as Kerbal Space Program do a [cheap approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patched_conic_approximation) by saying that only the gravity of the closest planet (weighted by mass) counts. If you're trying to build a similarly themed game that might be the most practical thing to do.