# Can the gravitational attraction from a particle ever decrease to zero if it goes far enough away from us?

Tags: particle-physics, gravity, quantum-gravity

As a particle moves away from us, its apparent size keeps decreasing. Is there a minimum apparent size that a particle needs to be before it becomes unobservable, and therefore is not in our observable universe, and therefore exerts no gravitational attraction?

Would general relativity and quantum physics agree on the answer?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/200781/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/331647/2451  and links therein.

Comment: I think it may not be a duplicate.  The question seems to be about the *apparent size* of an object vs its gravitational attraction.  It shows a misunderstanding of "observable" in the sense of "too small to see" vs "observable in the sense of "observable universe".