# Gravity against dark energy

Tags: gravity, spacetime, cosmological-inflation, dark-energy

If inflation of space makes stars and galaxies move apart from each other and gravity does the oposite, what happen to clusters of galaxies that aten't so close to get no effect of dark energy but although no so far for the gravity to not opose enough dark energy? Are they possibly moving apart but not at the rate that the Hubble constant predicts for that distances measured from Earth?

Comment: If there exists a balance of gravitational attraction and dark energy expansion between two objects, then, logically, with changing the magnitudes of either gravity or DE, the objects can be made to move toward or away from one another in an inertial frame.

Comment: That question already has an answer at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/527650/what-is-the-distance-from-an-object-at-which-the-gravitational-force-is-exactly/527679#527679